# Difference between I(x^3) and poly(x,3) in R for regression

Tags: r, statistics

I am a beginner in R so please excuse me.  I can't make enough sense of the documentation to tell the difference between these three forms of how I() and poly() work

using the mtcars dataset...

```
xx=lm(mpg~hp+I(hp^2)+I(hp^3), data=mtcars)
yy=lm(mpg~I(hp^3), data=mtcars)
zz=lm(mpg~poly(hp,3), data=mtcars)
summary(xx)
summary(yy)
summary(zz)
```

all give back difference results.  I thought ZZ would give me the same as XX or maybe even YY but it doesn't.  again if anyone could explain this to me that would be great

Comment: Read the documentation: `zz=lm(mpg~poly(hp,3,raw=TRUE), data=mtcars)`. `yy` is missing the lower order terms (i.e. fits y=a+bx^3).

Comment: `fitted(xx)` and `fitted(zz)` will be the same (up to minor numerical differences).

Answer (score 6):

`I(x^3)` makes a term of the third-order for which a coefficient will be estimated by `lm`.

`poly(x,3)` will make a third order polynomial and coefficients will therefore be provided for linear, second- and third-order terms of `x`. However, by default these will be [orthogonal polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) to the constant polynomial of degree 0, and the coefficients will not be what you expect. To avoid this use the parameter `raw=TRUE`.

```
coef(xx) ## All terms
  (Intercept)            hp       I(hp^2)       I(hp^3) 
 4.422493e+01 -2.945289e-01  9.114683e-04 -8.701086e-07 
coef(yy) ## Only the intercept and third order term
  (Intercept)       I(hp^3) 
 2.241691e+01 -4.312463e-07 
coef(zz) ## Orthogonal polynomials
 (Intercept) poly(hp, 3)1 poly(hp, 3)2 poly(hp, 3)3 
   20.090625   -26.045592    13.154568    -2.241893 
coef(lm(mpg~poly(hp,3,raw=TRUE),data=mtcars)) ## Same as coef(xx)
             (Intercept) poly(hp, 3, raw = TRUE)1 poly(hp, 3, raw = TRUE)2 
            4.422493e+01            -2.945289e-01             9.114683e-04 
poly(hp, 3, raw = TRUE)3 
           -8.701086e-07
```

However, you may run into issues with correlation between your terms if you do not use orthogonal polynomials, which is why that is the default.

Comment: How do you decide if you want to keep `raw=FALSE` or not ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel That is more a statistical question. Here some reasons on stats.SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/104085/229 https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234196/229